# Printing data in the Logcat using ASyncTask<> gone wrong

Tags: android, android-asynctask, logcat

I'm trying to print some data that i get from the `RiotApi` Api using `ASyncTask` and then log them in the logcat using `Log.d` for the data and `Log.i` if a `RiotApiException` exception is thrown by the `printSummonerData()` method. However, when i run the app it compiles and runs just fine and i get no `RiotApiExceptions` but the data doesn't get logged. Can anybody help me figure out why this is happening?

PS: I'm not sure if i should be using `ASyncTask` in the first place (i'm completely new to threads,Synchronous and Asynchronous Tasks etc) but from what i've read in the Android Documentation i shouldn't block the main UI thread with Network Requests etc. so i thought i should use `ASyncTask`. Please correct me if my assumption was wrong.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static String API_KEY = "MYKEY";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new DownloadSummonerData();
    }

    private static class DownloadSummonerData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            try {
                printSummonerData();
            } catch (RiotApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("LOL","Something went wrong!");
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        }
    }


    private static void printSummonerData() throws RiotApiException {
        ApiConfig config = new ApiConfig().setKey(API_KEY);
        RiotApi api = new RiotApi(config);
        Summoner summoner = api.getSummonerByName(Platform.EUNE, "XmaxUniverse");
        Log.d("LOL","Name: " + summoner.getName());
        Log.d("LOL","Summoner ID: " + summoner.getId());
        Log.d("LOL","Account ID: " + summoner.getAccountId());
        Log.d("LOL","PUUID: " + summoner.getPuuid());
        Log.d("LOL","Summoner Level: " + summoner.getSummonerLevel());
        Log.d("LOL","Profile Icon ID: " + summoner.getProfileIconId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have selected right device, right application, empty filter filed in logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't start your `AsyncTask`. Do his

```
new DownloadSummonerData().execute();
```

OR

```
// Assume DownloadSummonerData extends AsyncTask
DownloadSummonerData myAsyncTask= new DownloadSummonerData();

// Execute in parallel
myAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)
```

Comment: Yup, that was it! Thank you very much i forgot about executing it.

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail  I suggest you to use `rxAndroid` https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid . Here is great tutorial https://www.androidhive.info/RxJava/android-getting-started-with-reactive-programming/